i can't render partial js from controller rails 7
I've created my_portfolio.html.erb with form submission to controller with remote: true , the controller take the params and verification everything work fine with condition and code, but it's can't be render partial js the error say that
ActionController::UnknownFormat in StocksController#search
ActionController::UnknownFormat
Extracted source (around line #7):
 @stock = Stock.new_lookup(params[:stock])
  if @stock
    respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render partial: 'users/result', status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end

<h1>My portfolio</h1>
<div class="search-area">
  <p>search stock</p>
  <%= form_tag search_stock_path, remote: true, method: :get do %>
  <!-- form fields go here -->
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-9 no-right-padding">
  <%= text_field_tag :stock, params[:stock], placeholder: "stock ticker symbol", autofocus: true, class: "form-control form-control-lg" %>
    </div>


  <div class="col-sm-3 no-left-padding">
    <%= button_tag type: :submit, class: "btn  btn-success" do %>
    <%= fa_icon 'search' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  </div>

<% end %>
</div>
<div id="results">

</div>

app/views/users/my_portfolio.html.erb

class StocksController < ApplicationController
def search
  if params[:stock].present?
  @stock = Stock.new_lookup(params[:stock])
  if @stock
    respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render partial: 'users/result', status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end

   else
    flash[:alert] = "Please enter a valid symbol"
    redirect_to my_portfolio_path
  end

else
  flash[:alert] = "Please enter a symbol to search"
  redirect_to my_portfolio_path
end
end

end
app/controllers/stocks_controller.rb

alert("heelo word")
_result.js.erb



The core of the problem here is most likely that you're following an outdated tutorial.
Rendering JavaScript isn't actually something you do in Rails 7 unless you have no choice. That was how you sprinkled a little AJAX on top of older apps (Rails 4-6) that used Rails Unobtrusive Javascript (Rails UJS). It was not great as it in practice consisted of writing the same spagetti JS over and over to replace some element with escaped HTML content rendered on the server.
Rails 7 replaced Rails UJS and Turbolinks with Turbo which just does everything better. With Turbo you use format.turbo_stream to render partials and set the MIME type to text/vnd.turbo-stream.html. This just renders a chuck of HTML and Turbo will take care of the tedium of replacing the correct element. If you need to do something beyond simple frames or streams you write Stimulus controllers.
A more modern approach to writing a search form is to use turbo frames which is a bit simpler than turbo streams:
<%= form_with url: search_stock_path, method: :get, data: { turbo_frame: "results" } do %>
  # ...
<% end %>

<%= turbo_frame_tag "results", data: {turbo_action: :advance} do %>
  # ... this is where the results will get rendered
<% end %>

class StocksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_stock, only: [:search]

  # ...
  def search
    respond_to do |format|
      if @stock
        format.html { render partial: "search_results" }
      else
        format.html { render partial: "invalid_symbol" }
      end
    end
  end

  private 

  def set_stock
    return unless params[:stock].present?
    @stock = Stock.new_lookup(params[:stock])
  end
end

# app/views/stocks/search_results.html.erb

<%= turbo_frame_tag "results" do %>
  <pre>Render the search results here!</pre>
<% end %>

# app/views/stocks/invalid_symbol.html.erb

<%= turbo_frame_tag "results" do %>
  <h2>Please enter a valid symbol!</h2>
<% end %>

See

Working with JavaScript in Rails
Turbo Handbook
The Turbo Rails Tutorial


@Alex thanks for the edit. I just deleted the question since I didn't have to time to make the corrections.
